# Why is my Custom Combobox in javafx getting Nullpointerexception when closed

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, custom-controls

I made a custom combobox popup I plan on using for a bigger project the problem is, the combobox works like its supposed to but when i either close it, or touch the node inside I get a NullPointerException. Heres the code.

Main.java

```
package custompopup;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
     CustomComboBox cCBox;
     CustomComboBoxSkin cCBoxSkin;
     DecadeChooserfxController dc;

     public FXMLLoader fxmll;
     public static void main(String[]args) {
     launch(args);
}

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

      AnchorPane pane = new AnchorPane();

      pane.getChildren().add(cCBox);

      stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
      stage.setTitle("Custom Control");
      stage.setWidth(900);
      stage.setHeight(900);
      stage.show();

      cCBox.setOnMouseClicked(e->{ cCBoxSkin.showOrHide();

   });
} 


 public void init() {

    cCBox = new CustomComboBox();
    cCBoxSkin = (CustomComboBoxSkin) cCBox.getComboBoxSkin();
    cCBox.setMinSize(100,10);
    cCBox.setLayoutX(140);
    cCBox.setLayoutY(80);

  }
}
```

CustomComboboxSkin.java

```
package custompopup;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;

import javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class CustomComboBoxSkin<Year> extends ComboBoxPopupControl<Year> {
     public CustomComboBox<Year> customComboBox;
     public Pane pane;
     public DecadeChooserfxController dcc;
     public FXMLLoader fxmll;

     public CustomComboBoxSkin(ComboBoxBase<Year> cCB) {
         super(cCB);
         customComboBox = (CustomComboBox<Year>) cCB;
         getContentController();
     }

     @Override
     protected StringConverter<Year> getConverter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected TextField getEditor() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected Node getPopupContent() {
        setContent();
        return pane; 
     }

     public void setContent() {
         pane = new Pane();
         pane.setMinSize(50.5, 50.5);
         pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: slateblue");

     }


     @Override
     public Node getDisplayNode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
     }


     public void showOrHide() {
        if (this.customComboBox.isShowing()){
            this.customComboBox.hide();
           }else {
            this.customComboBox.show();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomCombobox.java

```
package custompopup;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class CustomComboBox<Year> extends ComboBox<Year> {
    public  CustomComboBoxSkin<Year> cCBoxSkin;

    public CustomComboBox() {
        cCBoxSkin = (CustomComboBoxSkin) this.createDefaultSkin();
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin(){
        cCBoxSkin = new CustomComboBoxSkin<Year>(this);
        return cCBoxSkin;
    }


    public Skin getComboBoxSkin() {
       return this.cCBoxSkin;
    }   
}
```

For simplicity I replaced the content the pane loaded with just the pane filled with color, but the result is still the excat same. I get a NPE upon closing the combobox.

```
Exception in the console 
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$createPopup$5(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.PopupWindow.doAutoHide(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.PopupWindow$PopupEventRedirector.handleAutoHidingEvents(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.PopupWindow$PopupEventRedirector.handleRedirectedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventRedirector.dispatchCapturingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventRedirector.redirectEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventRedirector.dispatchCapturingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please fix your code indentation? It is impossible to see where a method starts and where it ends

Comment: sorry will fix it

Comment: technically the reason is that the alias to the comboSkin in your application is not the one used in you combo (which overwrites the initial field value in createDefaultSkin). Which points to a major design/implementation flaw in your code: never-ever keep an alias to anything that you can just query ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help kleopatra